# How to concatenate two pytorch models by observation?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have two image classification models that have multiple images per observation.  The target variable is binary.  I would like to predict by observation.  How can I concat these two models when there are different numbers of images per observation, at the observation level?

Would I have to average out the predictions?  Or is there a way to program pytorch to consider the observation id?

I have my data class returning the image, label and observation ID.  See data class code below:

```
class image_Dataset(Dataset):
    '''
    roof data class    

    '''
    def __init__(self, csv_file, transform = None):
        '''
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        '''
        self.roof_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.roof_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        root_dir = self.roof_frame.iloc[idx,4]
        pic = self.roof_frame.iloc[idx, 1]
        label = self.roof_frame.iloc[idx, 3]
        img_name = os.path.join(root_dir, pic)
        image = Image.open(img_name)
        id= self.roof_frame.iloc[idx, 0]
        sample = {'image': image, 'id': id, 'label':label}

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return image, label, id
```

I have a model for my images of roofs and a model for my images of houses.  The same IDs are in both data sets.  An ID in roofs may have 4 pictures or less of a roof.  The same IDs in the house images may have 4 to 8 images in that data set.  I need to figure out how to predict on each image, average the results by for both the roof and house models for each ID, then concatenation them together for a final model at the ID-observation level.  I’m not sure how to ensure the models concat with the right ID.

Comment: Could you please expand your explaination a bit? You want to keep your two models separated, but you want to call something like `model(image, label, id)` and this model should decide if the data should be forwarded to model1 or model2?

Comment: More context added @cronoik